# How to remove slash from directory when there are more rewrite rules in the subdirectories on Apache?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've an Angular applicaion in multiple languages. After the build process there exist a distribution for each language. These are put onto the server in locale directories:

```
/en/index.html
/fr/index.html
```

Also all the assets, JavaScript files etc. are located per language in each directory. There's also a `.htaccess` file in each locale directory - only their last `RewriteRule` differs per language:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /fr/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the user is redirected based on the browser's language using PHP. So there's no `.htaccess` in the root folder yet.

The URLs look like:

```
example.com/fr/
example.com/fr/contact
```

I want to get rid of the slash of the root directory:

```
example.com/fr
```

How can I solve this?

---

I tried `DirectorySlash off` without success. I was also thinking about having only one single `.htaccess` in the root that handles the local directory and requests for all languages. But I can't figure out, how to solve it.

Comment: How many languages do you have? Is the language code always 2-digit lowercase a-z?

Comment: @MrWhite Currently just the 2, but there will be 15-20 in the future. And yes the code will always consist of 2 letters lowercase a-z.

Comment: What happens for requests to the document root?

Comment: The document root needs no further handling. It will redirect the user to the local-directory based on the browser langugae or the language selected and stored in the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule . /fr/index.html [L]
> ```

*Aside:* If you removed the `RewriteBase` directive and the `/fr/` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* then all your `.htaccess` files in the locale subdirectories would be the same.

However, I would go for creating a single `.htaccess` file in the document root (parent directory) instead, as you suggest.

In order to remove the trailing slash from the language subdirectory you do need the `DirectorySlash Off` directive - in the root `.htaccess` file. However, you also need to manually rewrite the request to append the slash in order to "fix" the URL. (mod_dir etc. won't work correctly without the trailing slash.)

Try something like the following in the root `.htacces` file, instead of multiple `.htaccess` files in subdirectories:

```
# Prevent mod_dir from appending the trailing slash to directories (with a 301 redirect)
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

# Allow mod_rewrite to match directories that do not have a trailing slash (when DirecrorySlash Off)
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

# Rewrite directory without trailing slash directly to the front-controller
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ $1/index.html [L]

# Front-controller to respective language controller
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/. $1/index.html [L]
```

Currently this does not do anything with requests for the document root, or "files" therein.

Also, any request for a language code that simply looks-like a language code is routed to that fron-controller, whether it exists or not (404). eg. `/ab/contact` is routed to `/ab/index.html`.

A request for `/fr/` (with a trailing slash) - if the user should request it - is handled by mod_dir in the usual way and will naturally issue an internal subrequest for `index.html` (if the directory exists) - the `DirectoryIndex`. This could be externally redirected to remove the trailing slash, although you should already be linking to the slash-less URL and the appropriate canonical URL set - so it shouldn't be an SEO issue (unless the slashed URL is indexed/linked to in the wild).

Note that by disabling the `DirectorySlash`, this is then disabled for all child directories as well, unless you explicitly override this.

Comment: That looks very promising. Thank you so much for your help.